# Getting an error while installing librosa

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install librosa package, but getting an error below:

Collecting librosa
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/7e/7a0f66f79a70a0a4c163ecf30429f6c1644c88654f135a9eee0bda457626/librosa-0.6.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: audioread>=2.0.0 in c:\users\chetan.patil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from librosa) (2.1.6)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8.0 in c:\users\chetan.patil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from librosa) (1.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=1.0.0 in c:\users\chetan.patil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from librosa) (1.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn!=0.19.0,>=0.14.0 in c:\users\chetan.patil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from librosa) (0.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.12 in c:\users\chetan.patil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from librosa) (0.13.2)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=3.0.0 in c:\users\chetan.patil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from librosa) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.3 in c:\users\chetan.patil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from librosa) (1.12.0)
Collecting resampy>=0.2.0 (from librosa)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/b6/66a06d85474190b50aee1a6c09cdc95bb405ac47338b27e9b21409da1760/resampy-0.2.1.tar.gz
Collecting numba>=0.38.0 (from librosa)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/45/d1c15c431d3361f074a25dcb278e79367b34ee44b6ca1bc2b7992e2382aa/numba-0.42.1.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: llvmlite>=0.27.0dev0 in c:\users\chetan.patil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from numba>=0.38.0->librosa) (0.27.0)
Installing collected packages: numba, resampy, librosa
  Running setup.py install for numba: started
    Running setup.py install for numba: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command c:\users\chetan.patil\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\CHETAN~1.PAT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gxhi2fsq\numba\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\CHETAN~1.PAT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-629a6nsz\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    TBB not found
    Using OpenMP from: True
    running install
    running build
    got version from file C:\Users\CHETAN~1.PAT\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gxhi2fsq\numba\numba/_version.py {'version': '0.42.1', 'full': '00b77e229d0f7808fc358c13f9158dae290b84a3'}
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6
    creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
    copying numba\analysis.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
    copying numba\appdirs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
    copying numba\array_analysis.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
    copying numba\bytecode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
    copying numba\caching.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
    copying numba\callwrapper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
    copying numba\ccallback.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba

```
copying numba\roc\tests\hsapy\test_ufuncbuilding.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\roc\tests\hsapy
copying numba\roc\tests\hsapy\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\roc\tests\hsapy
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\runtime
copying numba\runtime\context.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\runtime
copying numba\runtime\nrt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\runtime
copying numba\runtime\nrtdynmod.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\runtime
copying numba\runtime\nrtopt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\runtime
copying numba\runtime\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\runtime
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\scripts
copying numba\scripts\generate_lower_listing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\scripts
copying numba\scripts\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\scripts
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\servicelib
copying numba\servicelib\service.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\servicelib
copying numba\servicelib\threadlocal.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\servicelib
copying numba\servicelib\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\servicelib
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\arraymath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\arrayobj.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\base.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\boxing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\builtins.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\callconv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\cffiimpl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\cmathimpl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\codegen.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\cpu.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\descriptors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\enumimpl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\externals.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\fastmathpass.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\gdb_hook.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\imputils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
mba\targets
copying numba\targets\quicksort.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\randomimpl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\rangeobj.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\registry.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\removerefctpass.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\setobj.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\slicing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\smartarray.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\tupleobj.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\ufunc_db.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
copying numba\targets\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\testing
copying numba\testing\ddt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\testing
copying numba\testing\loader.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\testing
copying numba\testing\main.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\testing
copying numba\testing\notebook.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\testing
copying numba\testing\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\testing
copying numba\testing\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\testing
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\annotation_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\cache_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\cffi_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\cfunc_cache_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\compile_with_pycc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\complex_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\ctypes_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\dummy_module.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\enum_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\matmul_usecase.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\pdlike_usecase.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\recursion_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\serialize_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\support.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_alignment.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_annotations.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_api.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_array_analysis.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_array_attr.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_array_constants.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_array_exprs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_array_iterators.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_array_manipulation.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_array_methods.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_array_reductions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_array_return.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_auto_constants.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_blackscholes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_buffer_protocol.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_builtins.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_casting.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_cffi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_cfunc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_cgutils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_chained_assign.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_closure.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_codegen.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_compiler_lock.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_compile_cache.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_complex.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_comprehension.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_conversion.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_copy_propagate.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_ctypes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_dataflow.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_datamodel.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_debug.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_debuginfo.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_del.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_deprecations.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_dicts.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_dispatcher.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_dummyarray.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_dyn_array.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_dyn_func.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_enums.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_errorhandling.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_errormodels.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_extended_arg.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_extending.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_extending_types.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_fancy_indexing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_fastmath.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_flow_control.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_func_interface.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_func_lifetime.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_gdb.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_generators.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_gil.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_globals.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_hashing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_import.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_indexing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_inlining.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_interproc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_intwidth.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_ir.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_ir_utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_itanium_mangler.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_iteration.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_jitclasses.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_jitmethod.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_linalg.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_lists.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_llvm_version_check.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_locals.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_looplifting.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_mandelbrot.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_mangling.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_mathlib.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_maxmin.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_multi3.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_nan.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_nested_calls.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_npdatetime.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_np_functions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_nrt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_nrt_refct.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_numberctor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_numconv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_numpyadapt.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_numpy_support.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_objects.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_object_mode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_obj_lifetime.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_operators.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_optional.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_overlap.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_parallel_backend.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_parfors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_pipeline.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_polynomial.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_print.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_profiler.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_pycc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_python_int.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_random.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_range.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_recarray_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_record_dtype.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_recursion.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_remove_dead.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_return_values.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_runtests.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_serialize.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_sets.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_slices.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_smart_array.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_sort.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_stencils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_storeslice.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_support.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_svml.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_sys_stdin_assignment.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_target_overloadselector.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_threadsafety.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_tracing.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_tuples.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_typeconv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_typeinfer.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_typenames.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_typeof.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_types.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_typingerror.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_ufuncs.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_unicode_literals.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_unicode_names.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_unpack_sequence.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_unsafe_intrinsics.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_vectorization_type_inference.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_warnings.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_withlifting.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\test_wrapper.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\threading_backend_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\timsort.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\true_div_usecase.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
copying numba\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
copying numba\tests\npyufunc\cache_usecases.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
copying numba\tests\npyufunc\test_caching.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
copying numba\tests\npyufunc\test_dufunc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
copying numba\tests\npyufunc\test_errors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
copying numba\tests\npyufunc\test_gufunc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
copying numba\tests\npyufunc\test_parallel_env_variable.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
copying numba\tests\npyufunc\test_parallel_low_work.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
copying numba\tests\npyufunc\test_parallel_ufunc_issues.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
copying numba\tests\npyufunc\test_ufunc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
copying numba\tests\npyufunc\test_ufuncbuilding.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
copying numba\tests\npyufunc\test_vectorize_decor.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
copying numba\tests\npyufunc\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\npyufunc
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typeconv
copying numba\typeconv\castgraph.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typeconv
copying numba\typeconv\rules.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typeconv
copying numba\typeconv\typeconv.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typeconv
copying numba\typeconv\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typeconv
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\types
copying numba\types\abstract.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\types
copying numba\types\common.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\types
copying numba\types\containers.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\types
copying numba\types\functions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\types
copying numba\types\iterators.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\types
copying numba\types\misc.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\types
copying numba\types\npytypes.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\types
copying numba\types\scalars.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\types
copying numba\types\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\types
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\arraydecl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\bufproto.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\builtins.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\cffi_utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\cmathdecl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\collections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\context.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\ctypes_utils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\enumdecl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\listdecl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\mathdecl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\npdatetime.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\npydecl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\randomdecl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\setdecl.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\templates.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\typeof.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
copying numba\typing\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\typing
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\unsafe
copying numba\unsafe\ndarray.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\unsafe
copying numba\unsafe\tuple.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\unsafe
copying numba\unsafe\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\unsafe
copying numba\mviewbuf.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_dispatcher.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_dynfunc.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_dynfuncmod.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_hashtable.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_helperlib.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_helpermod.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_lapack.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_math_c99.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_npymath_exports.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_random.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_typeof.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\capsulethunk.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\mathnames.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_arraystruct.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_dispatcher.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_hashtable.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_math_c99.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_numba_common.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_pymodule.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\_typeof.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba
copying numba\annotations\template.html -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\annotations
copying numba\cuda\tests\cudadrv\data\jitlink.ptx -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\cuda\tests\cudadrv\data
copying numba\pycc\modulemixin.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\pycc
copying numba\runtime\nrt.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\runtime
copying numba\runtime\_nrt_python.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\runtime
copying numba\runtime\_nrt_pythonmod.c -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\runtime
copying numba\runtime\nrt.h -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\runtime
copying numba\targets\cmdlang.gdb -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\targets
creating build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\pycc_distutils_usecase
copying numba\tests\pycc_distutils_usecase\setup_distutils.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\pycc_distutils_usecase
copying numba\tests\pycc_distutils_usecase\setup_setuptools.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\pycc_distutils_usecase
copying numba\tests\pycc_distutils_usecase\source_module.py -> build\lib.win32-3.6\numba\tests\pycc_distutils_usecase
running build_ext
No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
building 'numba._dynfunc' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
```

I have already installed Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 but still getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve the error by installing visual studio tools 2017.Its about 1.5-4 gb file.
[check the image for file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA2cu.png)

Try to install only c++ tool from this file

[visual studio cpp build tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=691126&fixForIE=.exe.)